# Create multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a multidimensional javascript array like this :

```
array('cats' => array(
    'cat_1' => array(1, 2, 3 ...)
    ), array(
    'cat_2' => array(....
```

I would like to add/remove "cat_id" and "tag_id" according to my variables...

```
var filter = {cats : [[]]};

function generateArray(cat_id, tag_id, add = true){
  if(add == true)
    filter.cats = [cat_id];
    filter.cats[cat_id].push(tag_id);
  } else {
    //How to delete record the tag_id ?
    //filter[cats][cat_id].(tag_id);
  }
  return filter;
}

generateArray(1, 1, true);
generateArray(2, 2, true);
generateArray(2, 3, true); etc...
```

I have this error message :

> undefined is not object (evaluating filter.cats[cat_id].push

What's wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no C like multidimensional arrays in JS ,but you can put arrays in other arrays.

Comment: At least try to read the manual first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this code:

```
filter.cats = [cat_id];
filter.cats[cat_id].push(tag_id);
```

is that in the first line you set `filter.cats` to become an array with one element `cat_id` (on index 0). Then in the second line you try to access an element in that array with the index `cat_id` (not the value cat_id) which does not exists or is a number when cat_id is zero. Once you try to use the element as an object (by calling push on it) you get this error.

Instead of those two lines you could write

```
if (typeof filter.cats[cat_id] == 'undefined') 
  filter.cats[cat_id] = [tag_id]; // initialize element as an array object
else
  filter.cats[cat_id].push(tag_id);  // already initialized, so push
```

Here is some code to give you an example of how you may achieve your goal:

```
function addCatTag(cats, cat_id, tag_id) {
    var cat = cats[cat_id];
    if (typeof cat == 'undefined') {
        cats[cat_id] = [tag_id];
    } else {
        cat.push( tag_id );
    }
}

function removeCatTag(cats, cat_id, tag_id) {
    var cat = cats[cat_id];
    if (typeof cat != 'object') 
        return;
    var tag_idx = cat.indexOf(tag_id);
    if (tag_idx >= 0) {
      cat.splice(tag_idx, 1);
    }       
}

var cats = {};
addCatTag(cats, 'felix', 1);
addCatTag(cats, 'felix', 2);
addCatTag(cats, 'fluffy', 1);
removeCatTag(cats, 'felix', 2);

alert( JSON.stringify(cats) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, it is very interesting and it works with your code.

Comment: Glad it was of some use. I'd be happy if you'd accept my answer.